# passport.js RESTful auth in POST json or ? url extensions

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, restful-authentication, passport-local

Background:  We already have a server based on madhums [Node Express Mongoose Demo](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo).  It uses passport local and crypto (and Facebook but not important) - and salts the password into the DB.  But this server requires cookies and a _csrf.  Posting the csrf is easy enough, but I'm trying to avoid the cookies and session.  So I'm building a new server from the ground up to access the same mongoDB as the web server.

I'm trying to do a RESTful interface which is sessionless for a mobile app.

The reason for this question I'm not clear such an app (multiple IDE/platforms) supports the same functionality available in "curl --user", but I know how to produce POST at least for proof of concept.

The [passport-http 'basic' example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/tree/master/examples/basic) contains the following code:

```
app.get('/',
   // Authenticate using HTTP Basic credentials, with session support disabled.
   passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
   function(req, res){
    res.json({ username: req.user.username, email: req.user.email });
   });
```

explains how to test with this curl example:

> curl --user bob:secret http://127.0.0.1:3000/

How can the passport-http 'basic' example code be changed to accept the username/password in a POST, to allow this sort of curl request?

> curl -X POST -d username=bob -d password=secret http://127.0.0.1:3000/

I believe what I'm asking is how to change the passport/express/node.js/etc code to authenticate with a req.body versus a header (my limited understanding).

While best-practices suggestions are appreciated and encouraged, please be explicit if your answer does not answer the specific question above.

Comment: One mobile platform is Unity3D - if the passport-http 'basic' example is the standard way of doing things, maybe I should be brushing up on how Unity3D would authenticate for a RESTful API, rather than as per my OP.

Comment: I suggest you to use token based authentication approach using PassportJS and jsonwebtoken. If you need any help in this, then let me know.

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer the question.  Will keep it in mind for creating tokens (and possibly passport bearer strategy) - very useful.

Comment: On the mobile side - I have been able to verify that setting up headers according to this Unity3D guide successfully logs into the passport basic strategy - apparently identical to the "curl --user" way:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html

Doesn't technically answer the OP - but maybe adequate for anyone dealing with a similar use case.